# Two TextViews on the same dialog

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have two textviews, both they are getting text from the same dialog.  The following approach works.

But as you see, I am doing the same thing for both textviews, the only difference is their resource id. Is there a better way to handle?

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
  ........
  var firstPickerDialog = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon1);
  firstPickerDialog.Click += OnFirstPickerDialogClick;
  var secondPickerDialog = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon2);
  secondPickerDialog.Click += OnSecondPickerDialogClick;
  return view;
}

void OnFirstPickerDialogClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  var dialog = new PickerDialogView(ViewModel.Test1);
  dialog.DateSelected += (s, date) => ViewModel.Test1 = date;
  dialog.Show(((MainView)Activity).SupportFragmentManager, "PickerDialogView");
}

void OnSecondPickerDialogClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  var dialog = new PickerDialogView(ViewModel.Test2);
  dialog.DateSelected += (s, date) => ViewModel.Test2 = date;
  dialog.Show(((MainView)Activity).SupportFragmentManager, "PickerDialogView");
}
```

Comment: Create a method that does exactly that, but pass it the ViewModel you want to utilize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
var firstPickerDialog = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon1);
firstPickerDialog.Click += (s,e) => SelectDate(ViewModel.Test1, d => ViewModel.Test1 = d);
var secondPickerDialog = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon2);
secondPickerDialog.Click += (s,e) => SelectDate(ViewModel.Test2, d => ViewModel.Test2 = d);


void SelectDate(DateTime currentDate, Action<DateTime> setter)
{
    var dialog = new PickerDialogView(currentDate);
    dialog.DateSelected += (s, date) => setter(date);
    dialog.Show(((MainView)Activity).SupportFragmentManager, "PickerDialogView");
}
```

But this can cause memory problems, because you do not unregister your events. I'd go for this:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
    //........
    var firstPickerDialog = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon1);
    firstPickerDialog.Click += OnFirstPickerDialogClick;
    var secondPickerDialog = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon2);
    secondPickerDialog.Click += OnSecondPickerDialogClick;
    return view;
}

void OnFirstPickerDialogClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SelectDate(ViewModel.Test1, d => ViewModel.Test1 = d);
}

void OnSecondPickerDialogClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SelectDate(ViewModel.Test2, d => ViewModel.Test2 = d);
}

void SelectDate(DateTime currentDate, Action<DateTime> setter)
{
    var dialog = new PickerDialogView(currentDate);
    dialog.DateSelected += (s, date) => setter(date);
    dialog.Show(((MainView)Activity).SupportFragmentManager, "PickerDialogView");
}
```

Then you can simply call

```
firstPickerDialog.Click -= OnFirstPickerDialogClick;
secondPickerDialog.Click -= OnSecondPickerDialogClick;
```

to clean it up. Your `dialog.DateSelected += ...` has the same problem.

Always remember kids: **Every += should have a -= counterpart** Else the memory boogeyman will come and get you :)

Comment: I have an issue in the following `dialog.DateSelected += (s, date) => setter(date);` it is saying that `Delegate 'Func<DateTime>' does not take 1 argument`

Comment: ahh sorry. `Func<Date>` should be `Action<Date>`

Comment: Is that `Date` belong to  `Java.Util;` ? I guess it should be `DateTime`, is not it?

Comment: DateTime, or what ever type your `Test1` property has :) I just typed it in notepad ^^

Comment: Great! I will call counterpart, when I exit the page, is that oki?

Comment: Yes, that would be ok.

Comment: Please don't do that, please ^^ The question is listed in the question list. So everybody will see it. No need to link it under another question.